# Assigning an object within a synchronized block based on that object (Java)

Tags: java, synchronization

I ran into some (production!) code that looks like the snippet below:

```
synchronized(some_object) {
    some_object = new some_object()
}
```

I would expect this to be subject to all sorts of horrible race conditions, and that a second thread Could possibly enter this block one the new object is created. My Java chops aren't good enough to state definitively the expected behavior of above, so curious what you folks have to say before I refactor this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Francis says, this may not be a problem. Your snippet is equivalent to this:

```
SomeObject saved = some_object;
synchronized(saved) {
  some_object = new SomeObject()
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite written like that. In my case the class has the variable some_object which is used for the synchronization block, and this variable is being reassigned within that same block.

Comment: +1 the key here is that the synchronization refers to the object, not the reference.  After the `new` is executed and assigned, you are still locked on the old object. The new object is not locked at this point.  When the synchronized block is exited the lock on the old object is released, and if no other references to it exist it is eligible for gc.  If there's more code in the real sychronized block and it depends on the lock somehow transferring to the new object, then you may have a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jim. The fact that the lock is on the object and not the reference makes sense to me. What I was fuzzy on was when the object referenced by that variable changed, would another thread see a different unlocked object and enter the block again, or do the mechanics of a synchronized block prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4):

This could actually be OK depending on what is going on. You would need to understand the larger context. The synchronization will be on the object that's pointed to by `some_object` at the beginning of the block. There is not enough information from your description to see that it's a bug.

The synchronization itself will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronization is on the object that was referenced when entering the synchronized block. Pointing the reference to another object inside the synchronized block does not effect the synchronization at all. It is still synchronized over the "old" object.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty bad.  synchronized is best used on final class members.

The modern approach to creating an object in a thread safe manner is using AtomicReference compareAndSet in a loop as discussed in Goetz's Java Concurrency in Action (chap 15).  This does not block your threads and offers far greater performance than a synchronized block.

```
private final AtomicReference<SomeObject> someObject = new AtomicReference<>();


void buildIt() {
   SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
   SomeObject current = someObject.get();  //probably null, but doesn't matter
   while (true) {
      if (someObject.compareAndSet(current, obj)) 
          break;
   }
}
```